# vim-powerline plugin in ConEmu

Tags: vim, colors, conemu, vim-powerline

I'm configuring the Vim and ConEmu to work on my Win8 as on my Fedora distro.
After problems with getting to work the 256 colors in ConEmu for my color schema seoul256, now I have problems with the vim-powerline colors. In gvim there is no problem, only in the console. It looks that

[image]

So how can I get it to work?

Comment: May be your plugin is not xterm256 capable? Or it ignores term/t_co settings.

Comment: By asking on the plugin's issue tracker, maybe?

Comment: How have you installed that? I mean for example fonts etc. Is there any howto for Windows/Cygwin?

Comment: @DawidFerenczy Till now only official vim supports 256colors in ConEmu. Cygwin does not.

Comment: @Maximus: Oh I see. Is it because of Windows console?

Comment: @romainl a) Plugin authors cannot know everything about all shells. Especially about windows shells. b) vim-powerline is long since deprecated, no longer has an issue tracker and any issues with it will be closed immediately if you post them in *powerline* issue tracker.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy CygwinAnsi wiki describes the problem. You know that... Official vim, on the other hand, do what user ask it in config. That's why it able to use 256colors in ConEmu.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/25073399/588759