# Configuration of the airline plugin for ConEmu

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, conemu

I'm trying to properly set the airline plugin to work with my ConEmu and in the GUI version (this is on Microsoft Windows).

With gVim, there is no problem. Please look at the screenshot. I put all my custom configuration there for this plugin. I have no idea, why this doesn't work with the ConEmu? How can I fix that?

[image]

Comment: Same as [vim-powerline](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23446550/1405560). You need to ask plugin's author why they are not using xterm sequences...

Comment: What do you mean with the xterm sequences? AFAIK both airline and vim-powerline excepts 256 colors to work. And you also have to use patched font which contains additional characters or remap that characters in the Vim's configuration.

Comment: @Maximus, those things work with every other terminal emulator from xterm to konsole via iTerm or even freaking ajaxterm. What about making *your* terminal emulator work like the others?

Comment: My terminal working as expected. Vim works perfectly with 256 color mode. So, I believe, the problem is on plugin side. But, I can't make this plugin working even in mintty.

Comment: With "xterm sequences" I mean using xterm-256 color sequences of course.

Comment: On windows I got it to work on the [babun](https://github.com/babun/babun), screen: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6w28dzag52spgs3/babun.png). But I would really get it to work on a native win terminal, not through cygwin

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/25073399/588759

Answer (score 1):

Set the codepage for the console first:

```
chcp 65001
vim.exe
```

Comment: I was having problems installing Hack (aka Knack patched font) from Nerd-Fonts to get vim-DevIcons working on windows and this chcp made it work!!!

Comment: In ConEmu got to Settings then Startup > Environment and add `chcp 65001`